# Having a class with many static functions, and nothing else?

Tags: c++, static

#### Problem Description

I am wondering what is a best practice for classes that start having too many static functions, but no member variables.

```
class A {
    static void fooA();
    static void fooB();
    static void fooC();
    static void fooD();
    ...
}

/* 
 *   #include "A.h"
 *
 *   A::fooA(); A::fooB(); A::fooC(); A::fooD();
 *
 */
```

Or

```
class A {
    void fooA() const;
    void fooB() const;
    void fooC() const;
    void fooD() const;
    ...
};

/* 
 *   #include "A.h"
 *
 *   A a;
 *   a.fooA(); a.fooB(); a.fooC(); a.fooD();
 *
 */
```

#### Question

Is it best to just make an instance of the class and access the functions over the instance, or have the `static` keyword to all the member functions and access them in a static way?

I am asking this because my class has 8 static functions and it just seems visually weird.

Comment: Perhaps a namespace would be more appropriate. My general rule of thumb is No state, no class.

Comment: This sounds like a case for using regular function wrapped in a namespace.

Comment: At one time, using a class to hold a lot of associated static functions was *best practices* in C++.  Then `namespace` was invented, and that was a much better way to express the intent.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356582/c-are-classes-with-only-static-members-bad-practice-anti-pattern, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452161/helper-classes-with-only-public-static-methods, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434937/namespace-functions-versus-static-methods-on-a-class

Comment: @user4581301 A potentially useful exception would be a stateless class template since you cannot templetise namespaces. Doesn't apply to the question though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Namespace + functions versus static methods on a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434937/namespace-functions-versus-static-methods-on-a-class)